# how do i add delay in ant script?

Tags: ant

In my ant script, i have to execute this `Read.exe`

Read.exe will browse through version control and output a text file and which takes about a minute to complete. This text file is loaded as a `.properties` file for the antscript. However, it seems to me that i am unable to finish this task in time. By the time this `.properties` file completes, i have already executed another task which required some properties from this file. Therefore my question is.. how can i add delay in ANT script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<sleep milliseconds="10"/>
```

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sleep.html

Answer (score 4):

There is a `sleep` task: `<sleep milliseconds="10"/>`

**Edit**

You might also use `waitfor` task, as [described here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html).